# Event at value changed using jquery.val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an `<input type="text">` that have you value updated for many other scripts jQuerys, using the method `.val("value here")`. I need a new script to be run when the value of `input` has been updated. How to associate an event that'd make it for me?

Here is my code:

```
$('#PedidoTotalDescontoPadrao').change(function()
    {
        console.log('test');
    });
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: look into triggering custom events

Comment: Do you want it to trigger when the value is changed or when the box looses focus?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong event handler for what you need.

Try this one.

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 0):

The `change()` method does not applies to `<input type="text">` html tags. you may wan't to do it with `keyup()`.

```
$('#PedidoTotalDescontoPadrao').keyup(function() {
 console.log('test');
 // and this is how you'd trigger the other events you want 
 $('.something').trigger('click');     
});
```